# model.fit 0 validation performance. Model evaluate is correct

Tags: tensorflow

The validation accuracy seems to be zero.
Learning on Mnist Dataset. I copied the code from an Online Resource, and it isn't working properly.

Random Text to allow posting Question: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Output

```
Epoch 1/8
235/235 [==============================] - 13s 55ms/step - loss: 0.7066 - accuracy: 0.8715 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
...
Epoch 8/8
235/235 [==============================] - 13s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0176 - accuracy: 0.9941 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Score:  [0.052960414439439774, 0.9857000112533569]
```

Code

```
imports...


# Dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Cast to np.float32
x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32)
y_train = y_train.astype(np.float32)
x_test = x_test.astype(np.float32)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.float32)

# Reshape the images to a depth dimension
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1)

# Dataset variables
train_size = x_train.shape[0]
test_size = x_test.shape[0]
width, height, depth = x_train.shape[1:]
num_features = width * height * depth
num_classes = 10

# Compute the categorical classes_list
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=num_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=num_classes)


# Model params
lr = 0.001
optimizer = Adam(lr=lr)
epochs = 8
batch_size = 256
dropout_rate = 0.1

# Define the DNN
input_img = Input(shape=x_train.shape[1:])

x = Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=5, padding='same')(input_img)
...
y_pred = Activation("softmax")(x)

# Build the model
model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[y_pred])

# Compile and train (fit) the model, afterwards evaluate the model
model.summary()

model.compile(
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(
    x=x_train, 
    y=y_train, 
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_data=[x_test, y_test])

score = model.evaluate(
    x_test, 
    y_test, 
    verbose=0)
print("Score: ", score)
```

Comment: This fixes it- '''model.fit(
    x=x_train, 
    y=y_train, 
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))'''

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comment Section (Thanks to Medrik), for the benefit of the community.

The `validation_data` was passed in `[]` bracket instead `()` bracket. This issue was resolved when modifying below code from

```
model.fit( x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=[x_test, y_test])
```

to

```
model.fit( x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```